# js line is not accomplished after a draw

Tags: javascript

So whenever the moves variable is equal to 10 (why 10 and not 9? I dunno the moves variable increases 2 times instead of 1 the last time xD), the alert that the game is a draw does not happen and why's that?

I'm making a tic tac toe game by the way.

```
var moves = 0;
    var randomOneTwo = doGetRandom(1,2)
    var randomPlayBot = 0;
    var turn = randomOneTwo == 1 ? "X": "O"
    var score1 = 0;
    var score2 = 0;
    var win = 0;
    var canPlay = false;
    var dummy = score2;
    var dummy2 = score1;
    var whoWon = 5;

    window.addEventListener("load", _loaded);
    function _loaded() {
        document.getElementById("plpl").textContent = "The Player  " + turn + " is playing."
        var ids = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9'];
        var vale = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0];

        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById(ids[i]).addEventListener("click", doSet);

        }

        addEventListener("click", bot);
        addEventListener("click", doWin);


        function doSet(){
            if (this.innerHTML !== "") {
                return;
            }
            this.innerHTML = turn;
            moves++
            canPlay = true;

            turn == "X" ? turn = "O": turn = "X"
            document.getElementById("plpl").textContent = "The Player  " + turn + " is playing."
            turn == "X" ? vale[nc] = 100: vale[nc] = -100;
        }

        function bot(){
            if ((canPlay == true) && (document.getElementById("bplays").checked == true)) {
                do{
                    randomPlayBot = doGetRandom(0, 8)
                }
                while(document.getElementById(ids[randomPlayBot]).innerHTML !== "" && moves < 8)


                document.getElementById(ids[randomPlayBot]).innerHTML = turn;
                moves++

                turn == "X" ? turn = "O": turn = "X"
                document.getElementById("plpl").textContent = "The Player  " + turn + " is playing."
                turn == "X" ? vale[randomPlayBot] = 100: vale[randomPlayBot] = -100;

                canPlay = false;
            }
        }

        function doWin(){
            console.log(vale)
            let sum1 = vale[0] + vale[1] + vale[2];
            let sum2 = vale[3] + vale[4] + vale[5];
            let sum3 = vale[6] + vale[7] + vale[8];
            let sum4 = vale[0] + vale[3] + vale[6];
            let sum5 = vale[1] + vale[4] + vale[7];
            let sum6 = vale[2] + vale[5] + vale[8];
            let sum7 = vale[0] + vale[4] + vale[8];
            let sum8 = vale[2] + vale[4] + vale[6];
            for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
                if ((sum1 == 300 || sum2 == 300 || sum3 == 300 || sum4 == 300 || sum5 == 300 || sum6 == 300 || sum7 == 300 || sum8 == 300)) {
                    whoWon = 1;
                    score2 == dummy ? score2++:
                    document.getElementById("sc1").innerHTML = "O: " + score2;
                    for (j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
                        document.getElementById(ids[j]).textContent = ""
                    }
                    canPlay = false;
                    moves = 0;
                }
                else if ((sum1 == -300 || sum2 == -300 || sum3 == -300 || sum4 == -300 || sum5 == -300 || sum6 == -300 || sum7 == -300 || sum8 == -300)) {
                    whoWon = -1;
                    score1 == dummy2 ? score1++:
                    document.getElementById("sc2").innerHTML = "X: " + score1;
                    for (j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
                        document.getElementById(ids[j]).textContent = ""
                    }
                    canPlay = false;
                    moves = 0;
                }
                else if(moves == 10){

                    whoWon = 0;
                    for (j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
                        document.getElementById(ids[j]).textContent = ""
                    }
                    canPlay = false;
                    moves = 0;

                }
                else{
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (whoWon == 1) {
                alert("The Player O won and so he gets 1 point!")
            }
            else if(whoWon == -1){
                alert("The Player X won and so he gets 1 point!")
            }
            else if(whoWon == 0){
                alert("It's a draw and so nobody won any points!");
            }
            whoWon = 5;
            dummy = score2;
            dummy2 = score1;
            sum1 = 0;
            sum2 = 0;
            sum3 = 0;
            sum4 = 0;
            sum5 = 0;
            sum6 = 0;
            sum7 = 0;
            sum8 = 0;
            for(k = 0; k <= 8; k++){
                vale[k] = 0;
            }
        }

    }




    function doGetRandom(min, max) {
        let h = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
        return Math.round(h);
    }

    function doGetNum(n){
        nc = n;
    }
```

-------------------------------------------------------------//--------------------------------------------------------------------

**Edit 1: Html**

```
<h1 class="hd-1" id="plpl"></h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="sc1">O: 0</td>
                <td id="sc2">X: 0</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="tb-ttt">
            <tr>
                <td class="td-ttt" id="b1" onclick="doGetNum('0')"></td>
                <td class="td-ttt" id="b2" onclick="doGetNum('1')"></td>
                <td class="td3-ttt" id="b3" onclick="doGetNum('2')"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="td-ttt" id="b4" onclick="doGetNum('3')"></td>
                <td class="td-ttt" id="b5" onclick="doGetNum('4')"></td>
                <td class="td3-ttt" id="b6" onclick="doGetNum('5')"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="td2-ttt" id="b7" onclick="doGetNum('6')"></td>
                <td class="td2-ttt" id="b8" onclick="doGetNum('7')"></td>
                <td class="td4-ttt" id="b9" onclick="doGetNum('8')"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <form name="F">
            Player vs CPU <input type="radio" name="bot" value="" checked id="bplays">
            Player vs Player <input type="radio" name="bot" value="" id="plvpl">
        </form>
```

Comment: Please abbreviate your code, so we can actually check the problematic part

Comment: @GalAbra the problematic part is on the doWin() function, sorry for not explaining.

Comment: @GalAbra It is supposed to make the alert bellow you see, when the whoWon variable is equal to 0.

Comment: Why don't you change the `else if(moves == 10)` to just `else`?

Comment: There's another else there you see, and I need that one to return if none of the above are true so we can keep playing,

Comment: So I'm afraid I'll have to conclude that `moves` doesn't equal 10. You'll have to debug further...

Comment: in console.log(moves) it equals to 10 =/, but if I change 10 to 9 it also doesn't work :/

Comment: If you'll provide the full code (including HTML), it'll be easier to help

Comment: I've added the html.